# How to handle axios errors and show modal with error message

Tags: reactjs, axios

How can I show a bootstrap modal with error message when a axios request failed in react?

Here's a code example:

```
getItems() {
    return axios
        .get(apiEndpoint + '/items', {headers: UserService.getAuthHeader()})
        .then(response => {
            return response.data;
        }, error => {
            ServiceHelper.handleError(error);
            return error;
        });
}
```

Here's the method `ServiceHelper.handleError()`

```
handleError(error) {
    if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
        UserService.logout();
        window.location = '/';
    } else {
        alert('There was an error...');
    }
}
```

I want to show a bootstrap modal instead of the `alert` if an error occurs.

I need an global error handler. The modal should be shown if any api request in the whole project fails.

Comment: you can set state in else and in render make if state is true then open modal

Comment: isError:true in else

Comment: But I need a global error handler.

Comment: then you can return something in else  return "ERROR"

Comment: If I return something else, there is no modal shown because I can't render there anything...

Comment: May be you have to setup ErrorBoundary in React

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a App.jsx file including

```js
const app = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <ErrorBoundary/>
      <RestOfYourApp/>
    </>
   )
}
```

All you have to do is connect that ErrorBoundary component to redux, context or any other state manager that you have and in case any error occurs you should pass that to your desired state and render it inside the ErrorBoundary component.

This will render your modal on your entire screen and app as you needed regardless of which page the error happens.